# Custom Progress bars and Gauges

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-progressbar, gauge

I want to create custom progress widgets as shown in the image. After some research I found:

- For needle gauge i can modify [this widget](https://github.com/ntoskrnl/SpeedometerView)
- For Horizontal Progress meters i should customize the android native progress bar.
- For Water indicator i should create a custom widget using android canvas.

**My Question is**: Am I using the correct way to create and implement these widgets? Or Any better recommendations or tutorials which you think might help me create these especially the "Water Indicator" and Customizing the Android Native progress bar.

Thanks.

[image: Custom progress bars and gauges]

Comment: I'm looking for a Gauge widgets too, but as a full circle... The only implementations I've found so far (mainly http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/ and http://android.codeandmagic.org/android-gaugeview-library/)  have problems with xhdpi devices and Android 4.x versions... (I've also tried to run the relative projects but verified the compatibibility problems). I'll try the link you suggested for the Gauge even if it will require a lot of work to make it car-styled!

Comment: try this https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress

Comment: hw u made Horizontal Progress meter

Comment: Have you found the way? I am also looking for something similiar